# Python - Remove black outline & overlay PNG image on JPEG image

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I have two images:

Fragments from painting

[image]

Whole painting

[image]

I need to solve two issues:

1st. On the first image, I need to remove the black outline from each fragment. I've tried threshold and erosion, but neither of them worked. How can I do that?

2nd. I can't overlap the first image on the second, and I really don't know why. It always result on the first image overlapping it totally and putting black pixels where it should be possible to see the second image.

I'm using Python3 and OpenCV 3.2, on Ubuntu 18.04.

My program:

```
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys

plano_f = cv2.imread("Domenichino_Virgin-and-unicorn.jpg")
sobrepor = cv2.imread("Domenichino_Virgin-and-unicorn_img.png")

plano_f = cv2.cvtColor(plano_f, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY, -1)

#sobrepor_BGRA = cv2.cvtColor(sobrepor, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
sobrepor_BGRA = cv2.imread("nova_png.png", -1)
plt.imshow(sobrepor_BGRA),plt.show()

rows, cols, han = sobrepor_BGRA.shape
total = rows*cols

#printProgressBar(0, total, prefix="Executando...", suffix="completo", length=50)

'''for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        if(sobrepor_BGRA[i, j][0] <= 5 and sobrepor_BGRA[i, j][1] <= 5 and sobrepor_BGRA[i, j][2] <= 5 and sobrepor_BGRA[i, j][3] != 0):
            sobrepor_BGRA[i, j] = (0, 0, 0, 0)

        #printProgressBar(i*j, total, prefix='Executando...', suffix='completo', length=50)
        sys.stdout.write("\rExecutando linha " + str(i) + " de " + str(rows) + "...")
        sys.stdout.flush()

cv2.imwrite("nova_png.png", sobrepor_BGRA)'''

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS, (3,3))
#sobrepor_BGRA = cv2.cvtColor(sobrepor_BGRA, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY, -1)

sobrepor_BGRA = cv2.erode(sobrepor_BGRA, kernel, iterations=3)

#sobrepor_BGRA = cv2.cvtColor(sobrepor_BGRA, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA)

cv2.imwrite("nova_png2.png", sobrepor_BGRA)

#sobrepor_RGBA = cv2.cvtColor(sobrepor_BGRA, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGBA)
#plt.imshow(sobrepor_RGBA),plt.show()

sys.stdout.write("\nPronto!")

nova_img = cv2.addWeighted(sobrepor_BGRA, 1, plano_f, 0, 0)
cv2.imwrite("combined.png", nova_img)
plt.imshow(nova_img),plt.show()
```

Comment: What should the expected output image look like after overlapping both images? Wouldn't it just be the whole painting image?

Comment: No. The fragments don't fill the whole painting. The "holes" on the first image should be filled with the background image, i.e. the painting

Answer (score 1):

You can use bitwise operations to do this. The idea is to obtain a mask of the missing sections of the fragments then bitwise-or the two sections together. Here's two halfs of the image, one is the fragments you already have and the other is the missing sections.

[image]
[image]

We combine both halves to get the whole painting

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

fragment = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
whole = cv2.imread('2.jpg')
fragment[np.where((fragment <= [250,250,250]).all(axis=2))] = [0]
result1 = cv2.bitwise_and(whole, fragment)
result2 = cv2.bitwise_and(whole, 255 - fragment)
final = result1 + result2

cv2.imshow('result1', result1)
cv2.imshow('result2', result2)
cv2.imshow('final', final)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 0):

1st - your image is a jpeg image which means that the black lines around the pieces are going to be imperfect due to compression artifacts, a simple threshold or dilation isn't going to perfectly remove these.  You can try saving in a lossless format and modifying by hand in paint or something to clean up, you may even want to perform this step after doing an erosion and cleaning up most of it.

2nd - why don't you just copy with a mask using the `copyTo` function, here is an example:

```
import cv2

img1 = cv2.imread('x2djw.jpg')
img2 = cv2.imread('5RnNh.jpg')

img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thr, img1_mask = cv2.threshold(img1, 250, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
img1_mask = img1_mask[:, :, 0] & img1_mask[:, :, 1] & img1_mask[:, :, 2]
el = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3))
img1_mask = cv2.erode(img1_mask, el)
img2 = cv2.merge((img2, img2, img2))
img2 = cv2.copyTo(img1, img1_mask, img2)
cv2.imwrite('test_result.png', img2)
```